# Difficulty implement a C++ array of type abstract base class while having multiple different derived classes in it

Tags: c++, oop

We are coding a board game for an OOP C++ class where different spaces need to have different types of member data but we also want to be able to quickly access the data at any space.

The design we have right now consists of a "board" array that is length 40 and it is of type "space" pointer. Space is a fully abstract class with one virtual function in it. The virtual function is doSpaceAction(). The idea is that we will then create 7 different derived classes from this base class that will have the appropriate member data as well as their own unique implementation of doSpaceAction().

The issue comes with trying to access the member data of the derived class after the pointer to the instance of the derived class has been assigned to a space on the board. Below is some code that is analogous to what we are trying to do. We're all pretty new to OOP so we're not super sure if this is just a bad design for what we are trying to accomplish or if we just don't have the best footing when it comes to syntax. I know the compiler can tell the difference between what derived class pointer is stored b/c it can call the right version of doSpaceAction() but I just don't know what, if any, the proper syntax would be access the member data

```
#include<iostream>

class Space{
public:
    virtual void doSpaceAction()=0;
};

class spaceType1 : public Space{
public:
    int data1;
    int data2;

    spaceType1(int data1 = 0, int data2 = 0){
        this->data1 = data1;
        this->data2 = data2;
    }
    void doSpaceAction(){
        std::cout<<data1<<std::endl;
    }
};

class spaceType2 : public Space{
public:
    int data3;
    int data4;

    spaceType2(int data1 = 0, int data2 = 0){
        this->data3 = data1;
        this->data4 = data2;
    }
    void doSpaceAction(){
        std::cout<<data3<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Space * Board[40];
    spaceType1 * temp1 = new spaceType1(100, 100);
    Board[0] = temp1;
    spaceType2 * temp2 = new spaceType2(200, 200);
    Board[1] = temp2;

    Board[0]->doSpaceAction(); // outputs 100 as expected
    Board[1]->doSpaceAction(); // outputs 200 as expected
    
    
    //These two lines do not work
    //Board[0]->data1
    //Board[1]->data3

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? `Board[0]->data1` cannot work because `Space` has no such member. You'd need to cast the pointer to the appropriate derived class type first. Though such a thing is often a bad design (and doesn't seem to be necessary here at all anyway)

Comment: You would need to cast the base pointer to a derived pointer of the correct type to access data and functions that only exist in the derived class. You can use `dynamic_cast` for this, but having to do so is usually a sign of poor design.

Comment: Data members are not polymorphic. If you want that, then put them behind a virtual member function.

Comment: Why are you using a C-style array and `new`?  A better design would be to use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` + `std::make_unique`.

Comment: Why do you employ the array `Space* Board[40]`? The role of this array will be providing the way to access to 40 objects as `Space` (not as some derived type).
Therefore, trying to access the elements of this array as derived type is wrong (goes against the role).

Comment: The compiler (generally speaking) cannot tell at compile-time what concrete type a given pointer will be pointing to, so it doesn't try.  When virtual methods are present, the pointed-to object's `vtable` can be used *at runtime* to determine which virtual method to execute, but the compiler has to make all of its decisions at compile-time so it can't take advantage of vtables to decide what member-variables the pointer can dereference... hence only member-variables declared in the superclass can be explicitly specified via a superclass-typed pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here the compiler treats `Board[0]` and `Board[1]` as pointers to objects of type Space and doesn't acknowledge the inherited classes.
what you can do is to type cast the pointers to be pointers pointing to objects of the inherited class using `dynamic_cast`

hence you can do:

```
dynamic_cast<spaceType1*>(Board[0])->data1 = (value);
```

and

```
dynamic_cast<spaceType2*>(Board[1])->data3 = (value);
```